# which version of microsoft 2008 express for opengl es?

Tags: visual-studio, opengl-es

I'm following the openGl es 2.0 programming guide (gold book). It states that i need visual studio 2008 express. i've gone to the download site and there is an iso file that i'm not sure what to do with. so i clicked on the download individual product which led me to this page where i can download an installer.

[download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6506)

which version should i download? the tutorials in the book are given in C programming language.

thanks

[edit] i have to have 2008 as im running vista and 2012 is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition". Corresponding file for it is `vcsetup.exe` from the download page